# iOS - How to break app components into shared libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

I have an app that has many components.  In my case, there are several visual assets (a pie chart, a bar chart, a line chart, etc), and I'd like to be able to reuse those across multiple projects.

I have coded everything with a nice, top level delegate, which if implemented, the component can run on its own.  (similar to UITableViewDelegate, or the like).

What's my best bet for separating the code out?  It seems that the options are to [create a Framework](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios), or to use a [subproject](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/sub-projects-in-xcode/) in XCode.

Frameworks look pretty robust, but seem complex to create.  Also, with a framework, can you debug/step through code within the framework (assuming I have all the source, since I wrote it).

If anyone has done this for themselves, I'd be grateful for some insight.

Comment: I usually create a local Git repo and stick all my reusable code in there. Then just check them out when I need them in a different project. Only thing is to make sure and branch because I always end up tweaking my reusable code a little in each project.

Answer (score 0):

I like to package reusable components into [CocoaPods](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html) and either put them in a [shared spec repo](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html) or reference them [directly](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#using-the-files-from-a-folder-local-to-the-machine) in the project's Podfile.